# Retreive HTTP Response from API.post() function call AWS SDK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, post, aws-lambda

I'm calling a NodeJS Lambda function from my `ReactJS` front-end, and I would like to retreive the http response to get the value inside.
My code is the following to call the AWS function, and the `console.log(result)` is undefined

```
var result = await this.requestCSVDownloadURL({
                userId: this.state.userId,
                noteId: this.state.noteId
              });
    console.log(result)
```

The code of `requestCSVDownload()` is the following :

```
requestCSVDownloadURL(jsonObject){
    if(jsonObject.userId != null && jsonObject.noteId != null){
      var result = API.post("notes", "/request-csv-url", {
        body: jsonObject
      })
    }
  }
```

And I receive the following HTTP response which is what I want to get the body:
[image]

Does someone have an idea how to be able to get this http response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the payload property and parse the JSON response to get the body.

```
var result = await this.requestCSVDownloadURL({
                userId: this.state.userId,
                noteId: this.state.noteId
              });
    console.log(JSON.parse(result.payload).body)
```

Comment: I think the console.log needs to be the following : console.log(JSON.parse(result.Payload).body)

Comment: Yes, it does, please accept the answer if it helped you, so that others can benefit from it as well.